# Youtube player intialized error with huwaei mate 20 pro

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, youtubeplayer

I'm trying to use the Youtube Player Api in Android. I followed the examples provided by google, but I get the error: ERROR_CONNECTING_TO_SERVICE

The demo is working with all devices except HUWAEI MATE 20 PRO having 8.0. I don't know why it is not working with Huwaei mate 20 pro only.

Please give me suggestions or references why it is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: may not be supported @Dharmik Patel

Comment: But I didn't find any reference for that

Answer (score 1):

It appears, for now, that the API doesn't work on most Huawei devices.  This is because the use of API requires the use of YouTube software services. After testing on Huawei mobile phones, the device must first start the YouTube app, then the software developed by API can play YouTube videos (some devices do not need to start, as long as the device has YouTube on it).

You can use the `YouTubeStandalonePlayer` class to invoke a standalone activity with the youtube player as a work around. This works on my Huawei Y6 - 2019.